# Why does github cant find a page in my react file?

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I am learning react thru youtube vids and my code runs perfectly but when I upload it on github it somehow cant find one of the pages. Here's my code

```
import Nav from './Nav'
import Footer from './Footer'
import Home from './Book/Home'
import Templates from './Book/Templates'


const App = () => {
  let Page
  switch(window.location.pathname) {
      case '/':
          Page = Home
          break
      case '/templates':
          Page = Templates
          break
  }

  return (
      <>
      <Nav />
      <Page />
      <Footer />
      </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Heres my code for the navbar:

```
const Nav = () => {
  return (
      <header>
          <nav id="navbar">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/templates">Templates</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </header>
  )
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

While pushing code to gitHub remember that you are in the root directory of you project.
Follow below steps while pushing.

```
git add .
git commit -m "your msg here"
git push "repoURL" "branchName"
```

Comment: appreciate your answer but I don't know how to do that yet

Comment: than you should get some tutorial from youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEGIFZDyszA&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAKWClAD_iKpNC0bGHxGhcx